# Installed live USB PureOS on system running it already now unable to boot from encrypted partition

Tags: linux, gnu

A Librem Mini was running PureOS after years of using a Debian distribution of GNU/Linux... I used an USB live with the intent of installing on same "side by side" but something went wrong... Now it boots into grub rescue.

In an effort to figure out I successfully have now a clean installation running but still can not boot from original encrypted disk and when I enter the passphrase I can access files on it.

I include some relevant output, I hope. After many years of -- well, up till 1993 -- using VAX/VMS and again using GNU/Linux I ought to be more knowledgeable by now and ought to have been more careful -- as well as having backup before attempting the above.

```
o@goodlibremmini:/$ lsblk


NAME                               MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                  8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk  
├─sda1                               8:1    0   1.1G  0 part  /mnt
├─sda2                               8:2    0   1.8T  0 part  
│ └─luks-f7aa7190-da7d-42a3-a5e0-7fc394c24097
│                                  254:0    0   1.8T  0 crypt /
└─sda3                               8:3    0  69.1G  0 part  
  └─luks-38b56386-57c7-4f2d-bade-1540d9e79a3a
                                   254:1    0  69.1G  0 crypt [SWAP]
sdb                                  8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk  
└─sdb1                               8:17   0 465.8G  0 part  /media/goo/extusb1
sdc                                  8:32   1    29G  0 disk  
└─sdc1                               8:33   1   1.4G  0 part  
nvme0n1                            259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1                        259:1    0   1.1G  0 part  
└─nvme0n1p2                        259:2    0 930.4G  0 part  
  └─luks-8e3ccfb7-6888-4efb-84bb-7c8d5d9bfef1
                                   254:2    0 930.4G  0 crypt /media/goo/ebe9dff1-279e-4963-8276-84ac92d901ce
goo@goodlibremmini:/$




fdisk -l /dev/sda


Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 860 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x01af0f76

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          2048    2361344    2359297  1.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2  *    2361345 3762165060 3759803716  1.8T 83 Linux


root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo/Desktop# fdisk -l /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107837440 bytes, 976773120 sectors
Disk model: Extreme SSD     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 1048576 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x003f5ffe

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 976773119 976771072 465.8G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo/Desktop# fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 115.7 GiB, 124218507264 bytes, 242614272 sectors
Disk model: Ultra T C       
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1          64 242614271 242614208 115.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo/Desktop# 


Password: 
root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1 _dev_nvme0n1

Device /dev/nvme0n1 is not a valid LUKS device.
root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo# fsck /dev/mapper/_dev_nvme0n1

fsck from util-linux 2.33.1
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/mapper/_dev_nvme0n1
Possibly non-existent device?

root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1 _dev_nvme0n1
Device /dev/nvme0n1 is not a valid LUKS device.
root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p2 _dev_nvme0n1p2
Enter passphrase for /dev/nvme0n1p2: 

root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo# fsck /dev/mapper/_dev_nvme0n1p2
fsck from util-linux 2.33.1
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
/dev/mapper/_dev_nvme0n1p2: clean, 360390/60981248 files, 16513432/243894328 blocks
root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo# 


partprobe -s
/dev/sda: msdos partitions 1 2
/dev/sdb: msdos partitions 1
/dev/sdc: msdos partitions 1
/dev/mapper/luks-8e3ccfb7-6888-4efb-84bb-7c8d5d9bfef1: loop partitions 1
/dev/mapper/luks-f7aa7190-da7d-42a3-a5e0-7fc394c24097: loop partitions 1
/dev/nvme0n1: msdos partitions 1 2
root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo/Desktop#
```

ls /dev/sd*
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1  /dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1
root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo/Desktop#

Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev             32899936         0   32899936   0% /dev
tmpfs             6584500      9664    6574836   1% /run
/dev/dm-0      1849344848   7779096 1747554380   1% /
tmpfs            32922500     47212   32875288   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120         4       5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            32922500         0   32922500   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1         1128336    113636     939336  11% /boot
tmpfs            32922500         4   32922496   1% /tmp
tmpfs             6584500        44    6584456   1% /run/user/1001
/dev/sdb1       488266272 473713056   14553216  98% /media/goo/extusb1
/dev/sdc1       121277472     62368  121215104   1% /media/goo/CD93-F462
/dev/dm-1       959214904  49691320  860728336   6% /media/goo/ebe9dff1-279e-4963-8276-84ac92d901ce
/dev/nvme0n1p1    1128336    212660     840312  21% /media/goo/39be08d0-5941-42e3-8214-dbac93424297
root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo/Desktop#

Comment: can you edit the formatting of your question so that code blocks are more readable?

Answer (score 0):

A Librem Mini was running PureOS after years of using Debian distribution of GNU/Linux....I used USB live with intent to install on same -- "side by side" but something went wrong...now boots into grub rescue.

In an effort to figure out I successfully have a clean installation running but still can not boot from original encrypted disk but when enter passphrase I can access files on it.

I include some relevant output, I hope. After many years of -- well up till 1993 -- using VAX/VMS and again using GNU/Linux I ought to be more knowledgeable by now and ought to have been more careful -- as well as having backup before attempting the above.

o@goodlibremmini:/ `$ lsblk`

NAME                               MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                  8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1                               8:1    0   1.1G  0 part  /mnt
├─sda2                               8:2    0   1.8T  0 part
│ └─luks-f7aa7190-da7d-42a3-a5e0-7fc394c24097
│                                  254:0    0   1.8T  0 crypt /
└─sda3                               8:3    0  69.1G  0 part
└─luks-38b56386-57c7-4f2d-bade-1540d9e79a3a
254:1    0  69.1G  0 crypt [SWAP]
sdb                                  8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk
└─sdb1                               8:17   0 465.8G  0 part  /media/goo/extusb1
sdc                                  8:32   1    29G  0 disk
└─sdc1                               8:33   1   1.4G  0 part
nvme0n1                            259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1                        259:1    0   1.1G  0 part
└─nvme0n1p2                        259:2    0 930.4G  0 part
└─luks-8e3ccfb7-6888-4efb-84bb-7c8d5d9bfef1
254:2    0 930.4G  0 crypt /media/goo/ebe9dff1-279e-4963-8276-84ac92d901ce
goo@goodlibremmini:/$

`fdisk -l /dev/sda`

Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 860
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x01af0f76

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          2048    2361344    2359297  1.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2  *    2361345 3762165060 3759803716  1.8T 83 Linux

root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo/Desktop# `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`

Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107837440 bytes, 976773120 sectors
Disk model: Extreme SSD
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 1048576 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x003f5ffe

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 976773119 976771072 465.8G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo/Desktop# fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 115.7 GiB, 124218507264 bytes, 242614272 sectors
Disk model: Ultra T C
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1          64 242614271 242614208 115.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo/Desktop#

Password:
root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1 _dev_nvme0n1

Device /dev/nvme0n1 is not a valid LUKS device.
root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo# fsck /dev/mapper/_dev_nvme0n1

fsck from util-linux 2.33.1
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/mapper/_dev_nvme0n1
Possibly non-existent device?

root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1 _dev_nvme0n1
Device /dev/nvme0n1 is not a valid LUKS device.
root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p2 _dev_nvme0n1p2
Enter passphrase for /dev/nvme0n1p2:

root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo# fsck /dev/mapper/_dev_nvme0n1p2
fsck from util-linux 2.33.1
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
/dev/mapper/_dev_nvme0n1p2: clean, 360390/60981248 files, 16513432/243894328 blocks
root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo#

`partprobe -s`
/dev/sda: msdos partitions 1 2
/dev/sdb: msdos partitions 1
/dev/sdc: msdos partitions 1
/dev/mapper/luks-8e3ccfb7-6888-4efb-84bb-7c8d5d9bfef1: loop partitions 1
/dev/mapper/luks-f7aa7190-da7d-42a3-a5e0-7fc394c24097: loop partitions 1
/dev/nvme0n1: msdos partitions 1 2
root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo/Desktop#

`ls /dev/sd*`
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1  /dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1
root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo/Desktop#

Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev             32899936         0   32899936   0% /dev
tmpfs             6584500      9664    6574836   1% /run
/dev/dm-0      1849344848   7779096 1747554380   1% /
tmpfs            32922500     47212   32875288   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120         4       5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            32922500         0   32922500   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1         1128336    113636     939336  11% /boot
tmpfs            32922500         4   32922496   1% /tmp
tmpfs             6584500        44    6584456   1% /run/user/1001
/dev/sdb1       488266272 473713056   14553216  98% /media/goo/extusb1
/dev/sdc1       121277472     62368  121215104   1% /media/goo/CD93-F462
/dev/dm-1       959214904  49691320  860728336   6% /media/goo/ebe9dff1-279e-4963-8276-84ac92d901ce
/dev/nvme0n1p1    1128336    212660     840312  21% /media/goo/39be08d0-5941-42e3-8214-dbac93424297
root@goodlibremmini:/home/goo/Desktop#